# Given $f(x)$, a continuous function on [0, 1] st $f(x)≥0$ for all $x∈[0, 1]$, show that if $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=0$ then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x ∈ [0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

Given $f(x)$, a continuous function on the interval [0, 1] such that $f(x) ≥
0$ for all $x ∈ [0, 1]$, show that if

$\int_0^1 f(x)dx = 0$ then $f(x) = 0$ for all
$x ∈ [0, 1]$.

Is this true if $f(x)$ is Riemann Integrable on
$[0, 1]$ but not assumed to be continuous on $[0, 1]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is not identically zero on $[0,1]$, and $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=0$.  Then, there exists a point, say $x_0\in [0,1]$ with $f(x_0)>0$.

If $f$ is continuous, then there exists a neighborhood $N_{\delta}(x_0)$ of $x_0$ for which $f(x)>\frac12 f(x_0)$ for all $x\in N_{\delta}(x_0)$.

Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx &\ge\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}f(x)\,dx\\\\
&\ge \delta f(x_0)\\\\
&>0
\end{align}$$

which provided the desired contradiction.

Therefore, $f\equiv 0$.

---

If $f$ is not continuous, then $f$ can contain any number of isolated points on $[0,1]$ for which $f>0$, and $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=0$.

In fact, the set of points for which $f>0$ can contain an infinite number of points, provided the measure of the set is zero, and we still have $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=0$.  [See this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability).

Comment: Can you explain how you got $\int_{x_0 - \delta}^{x_0 + \delta} f(x)dx >= 2 \delta f(x_0)$?

Comment: Furthermore, can you explain a little more what we are proving with this contradiction? Did't we just prove that f need not be identically zero?

Comment: Sure; gladly.  $f(x_0)>0$.  $f$ is continuous \implies for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $f(x_0)-\epsilon<f(x) <f(x_0)+\epsilon$ whenever $x_0-\delta <x<x_0+\delta$.  This works for all $\epsilon$.  So, for $\epsilon = f(x_0)/2$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $f(x_0)/2<f(x)<3f(x_0)/2$ whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta$.

Comment: We assumed that $f$ was continuous and not identically $0$ with $\int_0^1 f(x) \,dx=0$.  We showed that this led to a contradiction.  Therefore, either $f$ is identically $0$ and continuous, or possibly not identically $0$ and not continuous. Thus, if we insist that $f$ is continuous, then $f$ must be identically $0$.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I clearly forgot that $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ was supposed to equal 0.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure! - Mark

Comment: How do we get $ \int_0^1 f(x)dx\geq \int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta} f(x)dx $ ?

Comment: @hallo97 $f(x)\ge 0$ and $0<x_0-\delta<x_0+\delta<1$.

Comment: How we can guarantee that such $ \delta>0 $ with $ x_0+\delta<1 $ does exist? If I start only with the fact that we get an $ \delta>0 $ with $ x_0-\delta<x<x_0+\delta $ and $ 0\leq x \leq 1 $ I don't see any reason why we can shrink down the existince of $ \delta>0 $ to $ 0<x_0-\delta<x_0+\delta<1 $.

Comment: Please review the definition of a continuous function.

Comment: I did this many times and I still don't get it.

Comment: Do you understand that there must be a number $x_0\in(0,1)$ for which $f(x_0)>0$?

Comment: Why $ x_0\in (0,1) $ inestead of $ x_0\in [0,1] $?

Comment: If there is an $x_0\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)>0$, then there is certainty on also in $(0,1)$ since $f$ is continuous.

Comment: What if $ x_0=0 $ or $ x_0=1 $  if we assume $ x_0\in [0,1] $?

Comment: Again, $f$ is continuous.  So there is a number $x_1\in(0,1)$ with $f(x_1)>0$ also.

Comment: Still doesen't convince me. $ f $ is continuous on $ [0,1] $ means with $ \varepsilon/ \delta $: $$ \forall a\in [0,1] \ \forall \varepsilon>0 \ \exists \delta>0 \ \forall x\in [0,1]:\\ |x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon $$ Just saying $ f $ is continuous and assuming there is $ x_0\in [0,1] $ with $ f(x_0)>0 $ is not enough in general to say that $ x_0\in (0,1) $.

Comment: @hallo97 As in the answer ... Suppose there exists a number $x_0\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)>0$.  By continuity, there exists a neighborhood $N_\delta(x_0)\subset (0,1)$ of $x_0$ such that $f(x)>\frac12 f(x_0)$ for all $x\in N_\delta(x_0)$.  That means that there is another number $x_1\in N_\delta(x_0)$ such that $f(x_1)>0$.  Either $x_0=1$, in which case $0>x_1>1$, or $x_0=1$, in which case $0<x_1<1$, or $x_0\in (0,1)$.  This should clarify.

Answer (score 0):

**Counterexample.** Let define $f$ such that $f(x)=0$ for $x\in[0,1[$ and $f(1)=1$. $f$ is Riemann-integrable on $[0,1[$, $f$ is nonzero and positive on $[0,1]$ and one has: $$\int_{0}^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0.$$ Therefore, you have to assume $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.