# What is the norm of $L(f)=f(x)-\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt$, $f\in C^0([0,1],\mathbb{R},\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

$|||L(f)|||=||f(x)-\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt||\leq ||f(x)||+\int_{0}^{1}||f(t)||dt\leq ||f||_{\infty}+||f||_{\infty}\leq 2\times||f||_{\infty}$.
Edit : $|||L(f)|||$ is never equal to 2.

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you can't find a function which makes the equality hold. Instead you should calculate the norm using the definition of the operator norm.

Define $f_n(x)$ as below:

$$f_n(x) =
\begin{cases}
2nx,  & \text{0 $\le x\le \frac{1}{2n}$ } \\
-2nx+2, & \text{$\frac{1}{2n}\le x\le \frac{3}{2n}$}\\
-1, & \text {$\frac{3}{2n}\le x\le1$}
\end{cases};$$

hence, in this manner, $||L(f_n)||=2-\frac{7}{4n}$, while $||f_n||=1$, which means, by definition, the norm of $L$ is $2$ (Notice that you have already proved $||L||\le2$).

Comment: Still, why 2 is never reached ? 
Thank you for your function, how did you find it ? It's there a tips or something ?

Comment: As I said you cannot find a single function making the equality hold.  You just need to take the definition of the operator norm (based on the supremum) into consideration. We introduced a sequence whose supremum is $2$.

Comment: It's the "cannot find" part that bothers me ahaha. It's there a proof that it's impossible to find one ?

Comment: Notice to have the value of integral equal to $1$ or $-1$, the function $f$ must be the constant function because of the continuity of $f$.

Comment: @Loca Indeed to have $||L(f)||=2$, the integral must be either $1$ or $-1$ because $||f||=1$. As I said in either case $f$ must be a constant function that leads to a contradiction. The intuition behind the sequence is to a construct a function whose area is almost $-1$ and its maximum is $1$. I hope this explanation helps you

Comment: I tried to prove it ! Let $f \not\equiv 0$. Let assume that $|||L|||=2$ that means $||L(f)||_{\infty}=|||L||| \times ||f||_{\infty} \Rightarrow ||L(f)||_{\infty}=2 \times ||f||_{\infty} \Rightarrow  sup_{x\in[0,1]} |f(x)-\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt|=2\times ||f||_{\infty}$ but [0,1] is bounded and close in $\mathbb{R}$, so $\exists x_{0} \in [0,1]$ such as $f(x_{0})=||f||_{\infty}$. Then we have $| ||f||_{\infty}-\int_{0}^{1}f(t)|=2\times||f||_{\infty}$ How can I keep up ? Thank you

Comment: Last idea that I have to finish the proof, even if it means exchanging f to -f we can have a positive value for the intregral. So we have : $\int_{0}^{1} -(f(t)+||f||_{\infty})dt=0 = \int_{0}^{1} -(||f||_{\infty}+f^{+}-f^{-})dt$. I can't go further. Thank you for the help again.

Comment: EDIT. I just realised my function has the same sign for $t \in [0,1]$ so obviously the function is equal to 0 always so there is contradiction.

Comment: @Loca $2||f||=||L(f)||=||f(x)-\int_{0}^1 f(x)dx||\le||f||+||\int_{0}^1 f(x)dx||\le2||f||\implies ||\int_{0}^1 f(x)dx||=||f||\implies f= constant. $ and this leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Why it's constant ? thank you.

Comment: @Loca Sure. Read this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2679022/integral-of-continuous-function-over-0-1-is-equal-to-some-upper-bound-of-the-f)

Comment: Thank you I think I got it

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
    L(f)& =f(x)-\int_0^1 f(t)dt \\
        &=\int_0^1f(t)d_t\chi_{[x,1]}(t)-\int_0^1f(t)dt \\
        &=\int_0^1f(t)d_t\{\chi_{[x,1]}(t)-t \} \\
    \|L\|&=\mbox{Var}_{0}^{1}(\chi_{[x,1]}(t)-t) \\
        &=\mbox{Var}_{0}^{x}(-t)+\mbox{Var}_{x}^{1}(1-t)\\
        &=x+(1-x)=1.
\end{align}
$$